# How correctly redefine \maketitle to add tagged elements in LaTeX?

Tags: luatex, expl3, tagpdf

I want to redefine `\maketitle` command so that all data (author, date, thanks and title) is tagged with the `tagpdf` package. In my opinion it should be inside the title tag. But when I do this tagging, I get an error:

```
! Argument of \end has an extra }.
<inserted text>
\par
l.41 \maketitle{}
```

Here is my code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tagpdf}
\tagpdfsetup{tabsorder=structure,uncompress,activate-all,add-new-tag=Title/P,interwordspace=true,tagunmarked=false}
\pagestyle{empty}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\makeatletter
\let\old@maketitle=\maketitle
\renewcommand{\maketitle}[1]{
\tagstructbegin{tag=Title}
\prop_if_exist:NTF{\l__data_of_title_prop}{}{
\prop_new:N {\l__data_of_title_prop}
\prop_put:Nnn{\l__data_of_title_prop}{@author}{H1}
\prop_put:Nnn{\l__data_of_title_prop}{@date}{H1}
\prop_put:Nnn{\l__data_of_title_prop}{@thanks}{H1}
\prop_put:Nnn{\l__data_of_title_prop}{@title}{H1}
\cs_new_protected:Nn \l__iter:nn
 {
\cs_set_eq:cc { orig@##1 } { ##1 }
\cs_gset_protected:cpn { ##1 } ####1
{
\tagstructbegin{tag=##2}
\tagmcbegin{tag=##2}
\use:c { orig@##1 } { ####1 }
\tagmcend
\tagstructend
}
}
}
\prop_map_function:NN \l__data_of_title_prop \l__iter:nn
\old@maketitle
\tagstructend
}
\makeatother
\ExplSyntaxOff
\author{alexandr Kozlovskiy}
\date{\today}
%\thanks{Alexandr Kozlovskiy} Why with \@thanks i get missing \begin{document} error?
\title{test document}
\begin{document}
\tagstructbegin{tag=Document}
\maketitle{}
\tagstructbegin{}tag=P}
\tagmcbegin{tag=P}
Test
\tagmcend
\tagstructend
\tagstructend
\end{document}
```

Comment: You select the code part in your post, and then click the `{}` button to format it as code.

Comment: @Phelype OleiniI hope,now it's all ok with my code?

Comment: Yes, that's it. I had already done that for you, I just told you for next time :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You were defining:

```latex
\cs_gset_protected:cpn { ##1 } ####1
  {
    ...
    \use:c { orig@##1 } { ####1 }
    ...
  }
```

where `##1` was `@author`, `@title`, etc. This would redefine `\@author` to take an argument. But then `\@author` is used in `\begin{tabular}{c}\@author\end{tabular}`, and takes the `\end` as argument, which breaks. `\@author` should just contain the author name, so the correct definition would be without the `####1`.

I also moved your code a bit. I renamed the variables to add a common module (`__kozlovskiy`) to their name, and I also renamed `\l__iter:nn` to `\__kozlovskiy_tag_elt:nn` (the prefix `\l_`, or `\g_`, or `\c_` is for variables only, and `\l__iter:nn` is a function.

I moved the definition of `\__kozlovskiy_tag_elt:nn` outside the definition of `\maketitle`: it's better to make all the definitions you need first, and then use them later. I moved the declaration of `\l__kozlovskiy_data_of_title_prop` outside the definition of `\maketitle` and set its items using `\prop_set_from_keyval:Nn`.

The `\thanks` is a bit different (because `\thanks` is a bit different than, say, `\author`). `\author` just stores the argument in `\@author`, whereas `\thanks` typesets a footnote marker at the point it's used and adds a *footnote* text to `\@thanks`, to be typeset later. However defining `\@thanks` with `\protected`, each `\@thanks` will expand to itself and you'll have an infinite loop. Thus you need to manually redefine `\thanks` to add that text to `\orig@@thanks` instead, which is the token list which will contain the footnotes and will be tagged.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tagpdf}
\tagpdfsetup{tabsorder=structure,uncompress,activate-all,add-new-tag=Title/P,interwordspace=true,tagunmarked=false}
\pagestyle{empty}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\prop_new:N \l__kozlovskiy_data_of_title_prop
\prop_set_from_keyval:Nn \l__kozlovskiy_data_of_title_prop
  {
    @author = H1 ,
    @date   = H1 ,
    @thanks = H1 ,
    @title  = H1 ,
  }
\makeatletter
\DeclareRobustCommand\thanks[1]{\footnotemark
    \protected@xdef\orig@@thanks{\orig@@thanks
        \protect\footnotetext[\the\c@footnote]{#1}}%
}
\makeatother
\cs_new_protected:Nn \__kozlovskiy_tag_elt:nn
  {
    \cs_gset_eq:cc { orig@#1 } { #1 }
    \cs_gset_protected:cpn { #1 }
      {
        \tagstructbegin{tag=#2}
          \tagmcbegin{tag=#2}
            \use:c { orig@#1 }
          \tagmcend
        \tagstructend
      }
  }
\cs_new_protected:Npn \kozlovskiy_maketitle:
  {
    \tagstructbegin{tag=Title}
      \prop_map_function:NN \l__kozlovskiy_data_of_title_prop
        \__kozlovskiy_tag_elt:nn
      \__kozlovskiy_original_maketitle:
    \tagstructend
  }
\cs_new_eq:NN \__kozlovskiy_original_maketitle: \maketitle
\cs_gset_protected:Npn \maketitle { \kozlovskiy_maketitle: }
\ExplSyntaxOff
%
\author{alexandr Kozlovskiy}
\date{\today}
\title{test document%
  \thanks{Alexandr Kozlovskiy}} % <- \thanks inside \title
\begin{document}
\tagstructbegin{tag=Document}
\maketitle
\tagstructbegin{tag=P}
\tagmcbegin{tag=P}
Test
\tagmcend
\tagstructend
\tagstructend
\end{document}
```

Comment: Ok,I expected get thing like:
```latex
\\tagstructbegin{tag=Title}
\tagstructbegin{tag=H1}
\tagmcbegin{tag=H1}
\tagmcend
\@author
\tagmcend
\tagstructend
\tagstructbegin{tag=H1}
\tagmcbegin{tag=H1}
\@data
\tagmcend
\tagstructend
\tagstructbegin{tag=H1}
\tagmcbegin{tag=H1}
\@title
\tagmcend
\tagstructbegin{tag=H1}
\tagmcbegin{tag=H1}
\@thanks
\tagmcend
\tagstructend
\tagstructend
\tagstructend
```
How to do this for lualatex? Thanks everybody very much for any help.

Comment: @AleksandrKozlovskiy Okay, I think I understood. I edited the code in my answer. See if it does what you need.

Comment: Thanks,now it works,as i expected. Can me please explain,why we use \DeclareRobustCommand and xdef.

Comment: @AleksandrKozlovskiy Because that's how `\thanks` is defined in the LaTeX kernel. I copied the definition and changed the second `\@thanks` to `\orig@@thanks` and added the `expl3` code to add the tagging.

Comment: It looks odd to role map the Title to P and then to use H1 for the content (and according to the pdf 2.0 specification H1 is not an allowed children of Title). I would use P or some new tag role mapped to P.

Comment: @Phelype Oleinik I mean,why instead \renewcommand we use robust command? Also i not understood,how you fixed error,which i had with @author?

Comment: @AleksandrKozlovskiy Because with `\DeclareRobustCommand` the command will not throw an error if used in `\protected@edef`, while with `\renewcommand` it will (and also because that's how `\thanks` is defined by LaTeX). The main problem with your code was that you did (the equivalent of) `\def\@author#1{\orig@@author{#1}}`, but `\@author` should not take an argument. `\@author` is used in `\begin{tabular}{c}\@author\end{tabular}`, so when `\@author` expands you have `\begin{tabular}{c}\orig@@author{\end}{tabular}`, and then you get the same error if you try to execute `{\end}{tabular}`.

Comment: @Phelype Oleinik Ok,and now i want to understood,why when we simple redefine \@thanks command,as we do it for other commands,we have infinit loop. as i understood,\@thanks call inside itself? why it happends? Why we must redefine \@thanks twice: inside \thanks and in \maketitle?

Comment: @AleksandrKozlovskiy There are a couple of different factors here. First, If you just treat `\@thanks` like the other elements, you get an infinite loop because the deifnition of `\@thanks` contains `\@thanks` (in LaTeX that doesn't happen because `\@thanks` is not `protected`). Second, my code was a bit wrong, then you needed to use `\__kozlovskiy_tag_elt:nn` manually. Sorry about that. I fixed it in the answer. Just replacing both `\@thanks` by `\orig@@thanks` in the code for `\thanks` solves the problem. I think it is correct now...

Comment: @Phelype Oleinik Thank you very much again. Now i want to understoode,how to get value of #1,i mean value of \author,\date,etc,to check,if it empty,or not,for example using function tl_if_empty,e.g how expand author,date,etc,to get value of this variables?

Comment: @AleksandrKozlovskiy Depends on what you want to do when they are empty. You can replace `\use:c { orig@#1 }` by `\tl_if_empty:v { orig@#1 } { <do something if empty> } { \use:c { orig@#1 } }`. The standard procedure is to predefine `\@author`, and `\@title`, etc. with the default value. For example, LaTeX defines `\@title` as an error `\def\@title{\@latex@error{No \noexpand\title given}\@ehc}`, so that when you don't use `\title`, an error shows up. As I said, depends on what you want to do.

Comment: @Phelype Oleinik I want redefime each command (\@author,\@date,\@thanks and \@title if this values are not empty). Tl_if_empty:VTF probably very good idea,but i get an error: You can't use `the character @' after \the.
<argument> @. for ####1,if i do it before setting #1 equals orig@#1. I tryed for debugging output arguments in log using \message{\tl_to_str:c{#1}} and it's almost works,but for \@thanks i get \thanks{Alexandr Kozlovskiy} instead of Alexandr Kozlovskiy.

Comment: Also now i tested compiled pdf in adobe reader,and noticed,that i haven't name of heads and text of my paragraph even if i delete \tagstructbegin and \tagstructend from \maketitle command. So,pdf incorrect even if we have heads and paragraph inside document,e.g without tag title.

Comment: @AleksandrKozlovskiy It looks to me, from the error message, that you forgot a `\makeatletter` somewhere. Try adding that before the code, and see if it works. I think you should ask a new question about the second problem: I'm not really an expert in tagging, and none of us can post code here in the comments. You'll have better answers with a new question

Comment: @Phelype Oleinik No,this error exists with makeatletter and only if we use \tl_if_empty:VTF. So,how to check,if \@author,\@date,\@thanks and \@title is empty? About pdf,it must be correct,because i deleted tag Title in \maketitle command,soall tags now inside tag \document.

Comment: @AleksandrKozlovskiy It's hard to say without seeing the code. Could you upload the code that produces this error to https://pastebin.com/ and then share the link, please?

Comment: Here you can find my code https://pastebin.com/9wUS3mn5. I even deleted tag title to show,that even in this case pdf document not correct shows by adobe reader.

Comment: @AleksandrKozlovskiy Ah. Replace `\tl_if_empty:VTF` by `\tl_if_empty:vF`. First, you need `v` instead of `V` because `V` takes a variable (e.g. `\@author`) as argument, and `v` takes a variable _name_ (e.g. `@author`). Second, your code only has a _false_ branch, so you want `F` instead of `TF`.

Comment: @Phelype Oleinik Control sequence with vF undefined,and generation it from NF (cs_generate_variant:Nn{\tl_if_empty:NF}{vF}) gives error: ! LaTeX3 Error: Variant form 'vF' deprecated for base form '\tl_if_empty:NF'.
(LaTeX3)        One should not change an argument from type 'N' to type 'v':
(LaTeX3)        base form only accepts a single token argument.

Comment: @AleksandrKozlovskiy Ah, sorry. In this case you can use `\tl_if_empty:NF`.

Comment: @Phelype Oleinik I have the same error,as for VTF. May be it's better for me to send issue on github,to ask developers of expl3 add command \tl_if_empty:vTF/VF,if now it impossible get values of \author,\data\thanks and \title to check,if it empty.

Comment: @AleksandrKozlovskiy No, this is not a bug, and `\tl_if_empty:VTF` (or `vTF`) would give the same result as `\tl_if_empty:NTF` (or `cTF`), but would be slower. I think you should ask a new question instead. Comments aren't really meant for long discussions like this

Comment: @Phelype Oleinik Ok,but how to solve my problem?

Comment: @AleksandrKozlovskiy Try `\tl_if_empty:cF`

Comment: @AleksandrKozlovskiy Right, since you don't _always_ define the `orig@#1` form of the commands, `\thanks@@orig` doesn't _always_ exist. Add `\def\orig@@thanks{}` at the beginning of the code. And `\tl_if_empty:cF`, I'm sure. Here's a working code: https://pastebin.com/sd04zS4X

Comment: @Phelype Oleinik Your code compile without errors,but now \@thanks not write in pdf,as it was before.

Comment: @AleksandrKozlovskiy Because at the time you patch `\@thanks`, it _is_ empty because we had to redefine `\thanks` to use `\orig@@thanks` instead. Try this one: https://pastebin.com/4n0f2cGb

Comment: Phelype Oleinik After your changes \@thanks still not write in pdf even if it not empty.

Comment: @AleksandrKozlovskiy This is what the output of the last code I sent you looks like: https://i.stack.imgur.com/uPwLb.png. If it doesn't work for you, _please_ ask a question. Sorry, I really don't mean to be rude, but I can't keep answering your questions forever. Please ask a question if you have further problems

Comment: @Phelype Oleinik I tested your code again,and i am sure,that \@thanks not writes in pdf. I even added log output,which shows,what property is empty. According to the log \@thanks is empty,but i added a value for this field. You caan see on my code on https://pastebin.com/F5X5PVZM

Comment: @AleksandrKozlovskiy Because at the time you apply the patch (`\__kozlovskiy_tag_elt:nn`), `\@thanks` _is_ empty, and will _always_ be empty with that code.

Comment: Ok,but \maketitle command using \@thanks command to get value,which i insert using \thanks{#1} command. So it must be empty only if i ignored \thanks command in the title of document. In this situation we can not redefine this command. So i expect,what i can check,if i imput \thanks in the title,or ignore it,as i do for other fields,such as \@author,\@date and \@title.

Comment: @AleksandrKozlovskiy As I said, `\(orig@)@thanks` is only filled when `\thanks` is _processed_ (which in the example is in `\title`). The order of things is: 1) define `\title` with `\thanks` inside; 2) call `\maketitle` 3) patch stuff (here `\@thanks` is still empty); 4) typeset title (here `\thanks` is used, so `\@thanks` is filled); print `\@thanks`. That's why that the timing is not working as you expect. **This is my last comment in this post. Sorry.**

Comment: @Phelype Oleinik Ok,but how correct check,if i \thanks or not?